# How can I run a WP-CLI command as authenticated user?

Tags: users, wp-cli

I've written a command for `wp-cli` called [`wp nurse`](https://boba.naughtysysadmins.com/git/Wordmin/Nurse). It is styled after the `wp doctor` command, except is meant to run the WordPress Site Health checks. Using the in-browser tool, all 16 tests currently pass. However, when calling it from `wp`, only 13 of the tests are succeeding.

```
ichabod:~ uplime% wp nurse check --all
+----------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| name                 | status      | message                                                |
+----------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| wordpress_version    | good        | Your version of WordPress (5.3) is up to date          |
| plugin_version       | good        | Your plugins are all up to date                        |
| theme_version        | good        | Your themes are all up to date                         |
| php_version          | good        | Your version of PHP (7.3.12) is up to date             |
| sql_server           | good        | SQL server is up to date                               |
| php_extensions       | good        | Required and recommended modules are installed         |
| utf8mb4_support      | good        | UTF8MB4 is supported                                   |
| https_status         | good        | Your website is using an active HTTPS connection.      |
| ssl_support          | good        | Your site can communicate securely with other services |
| scheduled_events     | good        | Scheduled events are running                           |
| http_requests        | good        | HTTP requests seem to be working as expected           |
| debug_enabled        | good        | Your site is not set to output debug information       |
| rest_availability    | recommended | The REST API encountered an unexpected result          |
| dotorg_communication | good        | Can communicate with WordPress.org                     |
| background_updates   | critical    | Background updates are not working as expected         |
| loopback_requests    | recommended | Your site could not complete a loopback request        |
+----------------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
Error: Only 13/16 tests passed
```

Digging through the code for these tests, it looks like they're failing due to not being authenticated (`rest_availability`, `background_updates`, and `loopback_requests`). For example, `background_updates` looks to call out to `GET /wp-admin/site-health.php?health-check-test-wp_version_check=1`, which fails, since I'm not technically signed into the dashboard. Short of creating a temporary administrator, and signing in with that (which sounds like a bad workaround), is there any way to authenticate with WordPress temporarily, so that these tests can pass?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default WP-CLI executes every command as unauthenticated (logged-out) user. To execute a command as any existing WordPress user you can use the global `--user` parameter, which accepts an user ID, login, or email address.

```
$ wp nurse check --all --user=1
```

---

You'll get all other global parameters listed when running `$ wp --help` or `$ wp COMMAND --help`.

> ```
> GLOBAL PARAMETERS
>
>   --user=<id|login|email>
>       Set the WordPress user.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to add any code afterwards to actually use that user? Those tests still seem to fail after running `wp nurse check --all --user=1` (I've removed the user creation code I was experimenting with)

Comment: @LuckyTheRabbit – You said you took `wp doctor` for an example. You need to look how `doctor` is making use of that user parameter and rebuild the same. Basically, I'd say you need to pick up this option and load the user in your code somehow.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I'll study that some more then. Appreciate the insight!